# What would happen if Olympus mons erupted?

Tags: geography, geology, terraforming, volcanoes

The Tharsis range is a quartet of immense volcanoes on Mars, one of which, [Olympus Mons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympus_Mons), is largest in the solar system. It is so vast that it cannot be seen from the surface; should you stand it’s slopes, the peak would be beyond the visible horizon. It’s crater is comparable in width to Paris.

When people set about terraforming Mars, the first thing they do is melt the core. (Don’t ask how). This melts the mantle in turn, which Olympus mons is still partially connected to. This raises the possibility that the volcano will become active again, which begs the question: *what happens when the largest volcano in the solar system erupts?*

Comment: Thanks for adding a link to Olympus mons on Wikipedia, stranger! BTW, how do you change the text on a link while keeping it linked to another site?

Comment: Actually all I wanted to do was to correct the typo "Olympus moss"; adding the link was an afterthought. Questions and comments are written in [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) -- to make a link write `[Olympus Mons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympus_Mons)`. (And on this site and some others, inline $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ works between dollar signs.)

Comment: Titanium? Do you mean the Typo caldera? Right next to the Autocorrect range?

Comment: This is either a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) (X happens, now what?) or far too broad (violating the book rule). Do you have a specific concern or question? What research have you performed?

Answer (score 10):

A quick google search revealed the following.

Olympus mons is what is known as a shield volcano.
Shield volcanoes are classified as very large with  broad slopes. Volcanoes like Olympus mons would create many large lava flows and would have limited amounts of explosive eruptions

Comment: The best example on Earth is [Mauna Loa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauna_Loa) in Hawaii.

Comment: And how would you get magma to form in the first place without water (which by the way, is scarce on Mars)? Magma is formed by decompression of mantle material, either due to chemical reactions catalysed by oceanic water, or else by heat transfer from the outer core to the mantle. Even in the case of mantle plumes, you have got to penetrate like 70 km of rigid crust, and 500km of lithosphere. There is no way Olympus Mons can erupt

Comment: This is an excellent [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609) demonstrating easily available knowledge through research.

Comment: @ArktourosUltorMaximus7600 After reading your answer and doing some quick research, I believe your comment, above, is a bit wrong. NASA currently believes that [Mars has a liquid iron core](https://mars.nasa.gov/news/453/scientists-say-mars-has-a-liquid-iron-core/). The fact that said core is so small could reasonably rationalize that Olympus Mons couldn't exude magma - but the claim that Mars can't have magma due to a lack of water appears to be specious. Without citations, I don't believe water is factually the problem. But what does that mean to the OP? In his/her world, it explodes.

Comment: @JBH Water is essential for magma formation. In a citation I just added in my question, water can cause a series of reactions, that decompresses mantle material, causing it to melt into magma.

Comment: @ArktourosUltorMaximus7600 I thought the consensus is that Mars has water, just no liquid one on the surface? This means in the lower layers of the lithosphere, there still might be water hidden.

Answer (score 4):

## Olympus Mons cannot erupt

There is one reason for this, which is really weird, but is real- **You need water to make magma**

Strange indeed, but this is what happens  on terrestrial volcanoes.

Volcanoes occur mainly due to tectonic activity (Ignoring mantle plumes for now), more specifically, the pushing down of the oceanic-plate, by the above land-plate. This means that the oceanic crust is driven down by the land crust, into the mantle.

However, at the same time, water also seeps along with the plate into the mantle. Remember that this was a oceanic crust being driven down, not the land crust.

Now, as water enters the mantle, it [catalyses a series of reactions](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.imperial.ac.uk/news/198796/study-reveals-water-deep-earth-triggers/amp/), that causes the mantle material to decompress and become a liquid, i.e. becomes magma. This liquid magma builds up under the crust, creating immense pressure, until it finally cracks the crust open and erupts out as lava.

On Mars, however, there is not much water. Most of the water has evaporated away, and whatever little water is present is present as ice beneath the surface. So, even if your terraformers managed to melt down the core and the mantle, then still Olympus Mons couldn't erupt at all, as there is not enough water to create sufficient magma for it to erupt.

Even mantle plumes don't stand a chance. Earth has a thinner crust, due to a larger mantle. This means that mantle plumes i.e. giant masses of mantle material from the mantle-outer core boundary, can easily penetrate the crust, and create massive eruptions, like the Siberian Traps.

However, Mars has cooled down significantly, which means that the mantle material has solidified into the crust, and made it much more thicker. In fact Mars' crust is [24-72 km thick](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abf8966#:%7E:text=Mars%20likely%20has%20a%2024,probably%20exists%20beneath%20the%20lithosphere.), with a 500 km thick lithosphere. In contrast, Earth's lithosphere is a mere 280 km thick. This means that even mantle plumes cannot penetrate the crust at all, as Martian crust is extremely thick.

No eruptions for you, Olympus Mons.

Comment: I tried to find proof of the statement, "you need water to make magma." I can't find it. I can find plenty of resources that explain that water in magma is required to create an eruption, but none that claim water is required to make magma in the first place. Can you provide citations claiming, in effect, that liquid rock can only exist in the presence of water?

Comment: @JBH added citations

Comment: I do not wish to argue directly with the theory that volcanoes need water to erupt as I am not an expert in this subject, but let’s give some comparison. It is clear that another planet in our solar system, Venus is volcanically active. The volcanoes on Venus have played a big part in what it is today, a barren hell scape. Science has given us no reason to believe there is water on Venus, and if there was it would surely be evaporated before it could do much. So if Venus has no water and is in fact volcanically active, why can’t Mars be?

Comment: Let’s not forget io, which is the most volcanically active body in our solar system and also happens to have the least amount of water of any body in our solar system. Multiple sources also suggest mars still has magma.

Comment: @HomegrownPotatoes Magma is formed by decompression of mantle rocks, which causes them to melt. On Earth this is caused by ocean water seeping into the crust or by heating of mantle material at the boundary between the mantle/outer core (Mantle plumes). Venus still has water, but it is not present in the liquid form. It is present deep in the crust as attached to minerals. Io's magma is caused by gravitational tidals forces which decompress Io's mantle to produce magma.

Comment: Mars lack either of these. Neither does it have a sufficiently hot enough core to release heat to decompress mantle rocks, nor is there water to induce decompression, nor does it have anything with strong gravity to induce powerful tidal forces to decompress the mantle material.

Comment: As for water trapped inside Venus- https://interestingengineering.com/science/venus-might-have-oceans-of-water-trapped-inside-its-crust

Comment: Fair enough, but it is known mars still has magma and with the water mars does posses, I think it’s possible. Don’t forget that within the context Olympus mons erupting is multiplied by the fact mars is being terraformed. There is a good chance that terraformers would bring up the water level on mars, but at this point it’s just speculation. For the context of the question I would say yes, Olympus mons can and would erupt, but agreeing with you, I don’t think Olympus mons would erupt on a normal day.

Comment: That's a good article, but it doesn't prove that water is required to form magma. It only theorizes (not proves, but good enough for government work) how a known deep-earth water cycle relates to magma formation. In other words, it connects two known processes here on Earth. That's a very long way away from saying (e.g.), "and therefore you can't have magma on Mars." Mars is believed to have a liquid core. Unless you're using that article to suggest Mars' core has a lot of water, the evidence is that rock can melt without water (which can be done artificially).

Answer (score 2):

This is a fun little What If.

Let's start by describing what Olympus Mons is. It's a shield volcano, just like the Hawaiian islands. The difference is that the Hawaiian magma plume moves over time. Olympus Mons was the great last gasp of Mars as its core cooled. Over time, the cooling crust got so thick that all of the volcanos on the planet got piled up in the one place where magma could still reach the surface.

The simple answer would be that it wouldn't do much. Shield volcanos are notorious for having eruptions where you can walk faster than the lava. Mars would briefly have a thicker atmosphere, and there would be a big ash plume.

Or, maybe, there has been pressure building up in the core for a very long time. It had a path to the surface a long time ago, but now all it can do is push harder and harder until the crust splits open like a grape and pours a huge new lava flow basin. That would also be cool.

Comment: Here we go. +1. Who cares if it's scientifically plausible that Olympus Mons can erupt? Given the OP's rule that it will, what would happen? Thanks, Robert.